# What's a better counting algorithm for Azure Table Storage log data?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm using Windows Azure and venturing into Azure Table Storage for the first time in order to make my application scalable to high density traffic loads.
My goal is simple, log every incoming request against a set of parameters and for reporting count or sum the data from the log.  In this I have come up with 2 options and I'd like to know what more experienced people think is the better option.

Option 1: Use Boolean Values and Count the "True" rows

Because each row is written once and never updated, store each count parameter as a bool and in the summation thread, pull the rows in a query and perform a count against each set of true values to get the totals for each parameter.
This would save space if there are a lot of parameters because I imagine Azure Tables store bool as a single bit value.

Option 2: Use Int Values and Sum the rows

Each row is written as above, but instead each parameter column is added as a value of 0 or 1.  Summation would occur by querying all of the rows and using a Sum operation for each column.  This would be quicker because Summation could happen in a single query, but am I losing something in storing 32 bit integers for a Boolean value?

I think at this point for query speed, Option 2 is best, but I want to ask out loud to get opinions on the storage and retrieval aspect because I don't know Azure Tables that well (and I'm hoping this helps other people down the road).

Answer (score 3):

Table storage doesn't do aggregation server-side, so for both options, you'd end up pulling all the rows (with all their properties) locally and counting/summing. That makes them both equally terrible for performance. :-)

I think you're better off keeping a running total, instead of re-summing everything everytime. We talked about a few patterns for that on Cloud Cover Episode 43: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-43-Scalable-Counters-with-Windows-Azure

Comment: I had already seen your blog post and downloaded the source before posting my question. I did watch the episode although it was terribly excruciating (iPad iTunes download had audio fine but video was horrific-stop jump ahead stop over and over again-making it completely unwatchable) and watching over the web on my laptop it kept buffering (speedtest.net said my con was 2.88 Mbps download). So it took me over an hour and a half to get through your 30 min episode. FYI, to those coming in, scrub to 9:30 mark where they start talking about patterns for tracking counts.

Comment: @smarx I thought you implemented comments for your blog. What happened to them? You should update the blog post and source code with your comments at the end of the show about using DeploymentId as your partition.

Comment: @smarx Finally, my thoughts about your answer: So you're saying that I shouldn't really use a log and count the log data b/c it ends up being a big pull to serialize to XML and send over HTTP b/c all aggregation can't be done locally. Does this mean it's better to have finer grained objects (less properties) b/c they're easier to pull back? And the best I can do for counting is to synch on the count per thread, is that garaunteed? I went the way of log data b/c I wouldn't have to have any locks at all.

Comment: I did have comments on my blog... removed them because there was nothing coming in but spam. (Most feedback goes to Twitter these days, and that suits me fine.) As to the task at hand, yes, I'm saying a log that you pull down to count seems suboptimal. May not be a big deal for small amounts of data, but since you're concerned about how many bits are used to store a boolean, I suspect you are anticipating a lot of data. There are a number of options, but I think the important thing is to maintain a total, not (or in addition to) a log.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. However, you didn't answer my other question was whether the Interlock on the per Thread per Deployment count was garaunteed. Is it?

Comment: @smarx if I append `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` to my RowKey (i.e. `RowKey = RoleInstance.Id + "-" Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`), would this eliminate the need for a lock on the counter for each RoleInstance?

Comment: I don't understand the question about guarantees... interlocked increment and decrement are thread safe (that's the point), if that's what you're asking. Not sure if the thread ID saves you or not... is it possible for the same thread to service multiple concurrent web requests (and thus to potentially make multiple async calls to storage at the same time)? Also, you don't want too many counters (if each thread had a unique ID--never reused--you'd be back to your original idea).

Comment: @smarx re: garauntees, can I assume since Interlocked.Increment does not throw Exceptions (besides NullRef) that it will **always** execute properly? re: ManagedThreadId, I'm assuming a thread pool for each WebRole Instance where threads are reused, one per WebRequest, so it wouldn't be the same as logging, i.e. max Rows = # threads in thread pool. Background summation can clean up old thread ids. Are my assumptions incorrect? How many threads are in a thread pool for a WebRole in Windows Azure?

Comment: Yes, I believe Interlocked.Increment is guaranteed to succeed. I have no idea how threads in ASP.NET work. They should work the same way in Windows Azure as they do anywhere else.

Comment: will your solution sum counters for Production and Staging deployments?